# How to write php codes inside html variable and defined all codes to php variable again for mpdf report

Tags: php, mpdf

I have faced a big problem in the **below code:**

```
//generate hotel table.
$table_hotel = '
//php codes here for generating table
';
```

I want to write down php code inside $table_hotel variable.

Please help me to sort out that problem

Comment: Have you tried something like this $table_hotel = '<?php echo "john"; ?> '; in `html variable?`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Diamond I sure hope not. That is no valid PHP.

Comment: i was trying to do that. But that is not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for functions instead of variables.

```
function table_hotel() {
     // Generate your table here
}
```

Then, if you want to generate a table you can execute the function as follows:

```
table_hotel();
```

In newer versions of PHP you can even do it like they do it in Javascript.

```
// Anonymous function
$table_hotel = function () {
    // PHP code here
}

// Generate table
$table_hotel();
```

You can find some more information about PHP functions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write down php code inside $table_hotel variable.

No, you don't. While you could use `eval()` (**DON'T**) you most likely needs just functions to keep your code organized:

```
function generateTable() {
    // Generate your table here
}
```

so when need to use it you just call `generateTable()`.

Here is the documentation [User-defined functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)